# Oracle.DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION. количество изменяемых строк в одной транзакции

Tags: oracle

Зарегистрировала табличку на нотификации.

```
DECLARE
    REGDS       SYS.CHNF$_REG_INFO;
    regid       NUMBER;
    nId         NUMBER;
    qosflags    NUMBER; 
BEGIN
    qosflags:= DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.QOS_RELIABLE + 
                DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.QOS_ROWIDS;
    REGDS := SYS.CHNF$_REG_INFO ('CALLBACK_PRC', qosflags, 0,dbms_cq_notification.updateop,0);
    regid := DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.NEW_REG_START (REGDS); 
            SELECT  id INTO nid 
              FROM TEST 
             WHERE ROWNUM=1;
    DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.REG_END;
END;
```

---

Создала CALLBACK процедуру "CALLBACK_PRC", которая в свою очередь инсертит данные в определенную табличку. столкнулась с проблемой update большого количества строк в рамках одной транзакции. т.е. выполняю :

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN (SELECT sv FROM TAB1 WHERE ROWNUM<=2000) 
      LOOP  
          UPDATE TEST
             SET STATUS =1
           WHERE ID = rec.sv;
      END LOOP;
  COMMIT;      
END;
```

Нотификация не работает. в CALLBACK_PRC даже не заходит. Выполняю commit  в рамках каждого изменения, нотификация работает:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN (SELECT sv FROM TAB1 WHERE ROWNUM<=2000) 
      LOOP  
          UPDATE TEST
             SET STATUS =1
           WHERE ID = rec.sv;
        COMMIT;
      END LOOP;
  COMMIT;      
END;
```

Подскажите, может есть какие-то надстройки Оракловые, которые бы помогли решить проблему с нотификацией update  большого количества строк в рамках одной транзакции.

Comment: Причем, при выполнении DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN (SELECT sv FROM TAB1 WHERE ROWNUM<=100) 
      LOOP  
          UPDATE TEST
             SET STATUS =1
           WHERE ID = rec.sv;       
      END LOOP;
 COMMIT;     
END;

Нотификация работает!

Answer (score 2):

Судя по [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_cqnotif.htm#ARPLS201) все честно:

> The notifications are published by the database **when the DML or DDL
>   transaction commits**.

Comment: Все понятно, только вот   DECLARE BEGIN FOR rec IN (SELECT sv FROM TAB1 WHERE ROWNUM<=100) LOOP UPDATE TEST SET STATUS =1 WHERE ID = rec.sv; END LOOP; COMMIT; END;    - работает, а больше 100(например 101) - уже нет.

Comment: @User_1991, работает ДО `commit;` ?